# problem with Using pivot table with Eloquent and Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laragon

Here is my problem. I have a table called user and table called skills, also I have a pivot table that connects these two called EmployeeSkill. I am trying to fetch the skills that belong to the user but when i use tinker it returns Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pfe_sirh_db.skill_user' doesn't exist (SQL: select `skills`.*, `skill_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `skill_user`.`skill_id` as `pivot_skill_id`, `skill_user`.`employee_id` as `pivot_employee_id` from `skills` inner join `skill_user` on `skills`.`id` = `skill_user`.`skill_id` where `skill_user`.`user_id` = 1)' and am using swagger by the way it returns this "withTimestamps": false

```
    class User extends Authenticatable{

protected $table = "users";
   public function skills()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Skill::class);
    }
}
```

and

```
   class Skill extends Model
    {
       public function User()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
        }

}
```

and the pivot table

```
    class EmployeeSkill extends Model
{
    protected $table = "employee_skills";

    protected $fillable = [
        'employee_id', 'skill_id', 'note'
    ];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pivot table should be named `skill_user` (**singular**) following the model name they belong to. And you don't need a EmployeeSkill model for this relation to work, you only need the table.

As said in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

> to determine the table name of the relationship's joining table, **Eloquent will join the two related model names in alphabetical order**.  However, you are free to override this convention. You may do so by passing a second argument to the belongsToMany method

And then you should exclude this line:

`protected $table = "employee_skills";`

change your table name to `skill_user`

And in your pivot table you should use `user_id` as a foreign key

You can retrieve all skills from a user by doing this:

`$user = User::find(1);
$user->skills();`

This will give you all the skills from the user with the id 1

Be aware that you can use any table name and any foreign key name but if you do that you need to specify the names on the relations. So i recommend you doing what i 've told you, since is the standard way

Comment: $user->skills();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany {#3054
     +withTimestamps: false,

Comment: $user->skills;
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'employee_skill.user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `skills`.*, `employee_skill`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `employee_skill`.`skill_id` as `pivot_skill_id` from 
`skills` inner join `employee_skill` on `skills`.`id` = `employee_skill`.`skill_id` where `employee_skill`.`user_id` = 1)'

Comment: hey, a realize i've made some mistake. Take a look at my answer now